# Jooq - Plain SQL Parameterized Array/List

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jooq

I would like to supply collection/arrays in the "IN" parameter but I got

When I used array:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Cannot bind ARRAY types in dialect MYSQL
```

When I used list:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
```

Here is my plain sql:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(foo.reply = 'Y') yes " +
            "FROM foo " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN bar " +
            "ON foo.id = bar.foo_id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "foo.id = ? " +
            "AND foo.some_id IN (?) "; //this is the part I would like to use array or list
```

Here's how I execute it

```
dslContext.fetch(sql, val(fooId), val(someIds))
                    .into(Summary.class);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that with single bind variables (except in PostgreSQL with arrays). But you can use nested plain SQL query parts in jOOQ as such:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(foo.reply = 'Y') yes " +
            "FROM foo " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN bar " +
            "ON foo.id = bar.foo_id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "foo.id = {0} " +
            "AND foo.some_id IN ({1}) "; // Use the {0}, {1} placeholders
```

And then

```
dslContext.fetch(sql, 
               val(fooId), 
               DSL.list(someIds.stream().map(DSL::val).collect(toList())))
          .into(Summary.class);
```

See also [`DSL.list(QueryPart...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#list-java.util.Collection-)